# How do I get character by character input in c++?

Tags: c++, c, io, getchar

First I need to read two integers N & Q separated by space. I am doing this using cin. Then in next two lines two binary numbers each of N digits follow. I am trying to read these numbers bit by bit using getchar() and putting them into int vector but it is printing garbage values. Is there a problem with new line character. I know I could first read them into a string and then put them into vector but I wanted to do this way. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int N;
    int Q;
    cin >>N>>Q;
    string A, B;
    //cin >> A>>B;
    vector <int> Abit;
    vector <int> Bbit;

    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        char c= (int) getchar();
        Abit.push_back(c);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
    //  cout << Abit.at(i);
        char c= (int) getchar();
        Bbit.push_back(c);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        cout << Abit.at(i);
    //  char c= (int) getchar();
    //  Bbit.push_back(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are reading in two strings when you do `cin >> A >> B`? Maybe try getting rid of that?

Comment: @Xymostech yeah, sorry about that. I have updated the question. It's printing garbage values.

Comment: You're getting the character values of `0` and `1`, probably. Have you tried doing something like `getchar() - '0'`?

Comment: @Xymostech Thanks, that solved half of my problem. Now the only thing is my vector first for loop is reading new line character I press after getting N & Q. So first bit of my vector is messed up but rest are alright. Any ideas how can I solve that?

Comment: Are the two bit strings separated by whitespace. I.e. `10110100 10110111` ? I have to assume so, as this becomes trivial if they are.

Comment: @Xymostech Solved it. Just added two getline where I am pressing enter.

Answer (score 4):

You can just simply do it by reading a character.

```
char c;
for ( int i = 0; i < N; ++i ）{
  cin >> c;
  Abit.push_back(c);
}
for ( int i = 0; i < N; ++i ）{
  cin >> c;
  Bbit.push_back(c);
}
```

the >> operator will avoid any form of seprate, space, new line, etc.

Comment: Whitespace skipping can be controlled with `ios::skip_ws`.

Answer (score 3):

Each time you type a character and press return, `getchar` will be called twice - the first time for the character you input, and the second time for the '\n' character. So, if you input `1 2 3 4 5`, you will push back in your vector the following: `10, 49, 10, 50, 10`.

The first `10` if for the remained `\n` character from the `cin << N << Q;` call.

The other `49` stands for the ASCII `1`, and the `50` for the ASCII `2`.

You may want to read entire line into the string, and then to extract the characters out from the string. Of course, you still need to to convert ASCII characters to integers, but you can do that by subtracting the character value from the value of ASCII `0`: `c - '0'`.

Also, you can remove ignore all before and including newline by reading them before the actual digit:

```
 while(getchar() != '\n');
 char c= (int) getchar() - '0';
```

Better way, which would skip all newlines before digit is suggested by [Charlie Burns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1828382/charlie-burns). Tou just need to read all newline characters before the actual digit:

```
    char c;
    while((c = getchar()) == '\n');
    Abit.push_back(c - '0');
```

Comment: That code snippet, "while(getchar() != '\n');" doesn't look like it would skip newlines. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you want something like "while((c = getchar()) == '\n');" ? Then c contains the first char that is not a newline?

Comment: It would read all characters before `\n` character including the `\n` character, when it would break.

Comment: @CharlieBurns yes, that is a better suggestion.